# Number of microstates compatible with two boxes

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematics, probability

From my notes I have:

> [image]
>
> From one point of view there are many more microstates compatible with the LHS than the RHS, in fact the relation between the number of microstates is
>   $$\frac{n_B}{n_A}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^N$$

I cannot understand why we have the $1/2$ to the power $N$. I would have thought that it would be 
$$\frac{n_B}{n_A}=\frac{1}{2}$$
as there is half the room. Could someone please explain the reasoning behind the power of $N$ please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ratio between avaible microstates is given by the following ratio:

$$ \frac{n_{B}}{n_{A}}=\frac{\int_{V/2}d^{3N}q d^{3N}p}{\int_{V}d^{3N}q d^{3N}p}=\frac{\int_{V/2}d^{3N}q}{\int_{V}d^{3N}q}=\frac{\int_{V/2}d^{3}q_1 \int_{V/2}d^3 q_{2}\dots }{\int_{V}d^{3}q_1 \int_{V}d^3 q_{2}\dots}=\left( V/2 \right)^N/V^N=\frac{1}{2^N}$$
where $N$ is the number of particles and $V$ is the volume of the box.

Answer (score 3):

This may be the argument: you have $N$ particles, and for each one you can put it on the left side or on the right side. Each of these choices, for each particle, leads to a different microstate. There are $2^N$ possible choices you can make for how to distribute the $N$ particles between the left and right halves of the box (assuming the particles are distinguishable), and thus $2^N$ microstates, but only one of these microstates has the particles all on the right side. So the relation is $n_B/n_A = 1/2^N$. This assumes that diagram A is meant to represent the macrostate containing *all* possible microstates, even those in which the particles do happen to all wind up on the right side.

If that sounds somewhat unsatisfying, here's a slightly better argument. Suppose the large box is divided into $2M$ little squares, where $M$ is very large. The number of ways to place the particles into these $2M$ squares is
$$n_A = \binom{2M - 1 + N}{N} = \frac{(2M - 1 + N)!}{N!(2M - 1)!}$$
now assuming the particles are *indistinguishable* (though it turns out not to matter, since distinguishable particles just have an extra $N!$ in both this expression and the following one). But the number of ways to place the particles into the $M$ squares on the right half of the box is
$$n_B = \binom{M - 1 + N}{N} = \frac{(M - 1 + N)!}{N!(M - 1)!}$$
The ratio of these is
$$\frac{n_B}{n_A} = \frac{(M - 1 + N)!}{N!(M - 1)!}\frac{N!(2M - 1)!}{(2M - 1 + N)!}
= \frac{M(M+1)\cdots(2M - 1)}{(M+N)(M+N+1)\cdots(2M-1+N)}$$
and if you take the logarithm, you get
$$\begin{align}
\ln\frac{(M - 1 + N)!}{(M - 1)!}&\frac{(2M - 1)!}{(2M - 1 + N)!} \\
\approx\ &(M-1+N)\ln(M-1+N) - (M-1+N) \\
&- (M-1)\ln(M-1) + (M-1) \\
&+ (2M-1)\ln(2M-1) - (2M-1) \\
&- (2M-1+N)\ln(2M-1+N) + (2M-1+N) \\
\approx\ &(M+N)\ln(M+N) - M\ln M + 2M\ln(2M) - (2M+N)\ln(2M+N) \\
=\ &M\biggl(\ln\frac{4}{2+r} + (1+r)\ln\frac{1+r}{2+r}\biggr)
\end{align}$$
where $r = \frac{N}{M}$. In the limit of extremely large $M\gg N$, so that $r\to 0$, this can be approximated as
$$\ln\frac{n_B}{n_A} = -Mr\ln 2 + \mathcal{O}(r^2) = -N\ln 2 + \mathcal{O}(r^2)$$
which leads directly to
$$\frac{n_B}{n_A} = \frac{1}{2^N}$$
But again, this is based on the assumption that state A represents the macrostate consisting of *all* possible microstates, even those where the particles are all on one side.